# Iterating over all hyperlinks in an excel sheet using OpenXML doesn't return all hyperlinks

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am observing a very weird behavior here. I have an excel document (.xlsx) and My goal is to edit all the hyperlinks that meet a certain criteria.

The first time I iterate, I am able to edit most of the links. There are 4 links that still remain. Then I run the program again. Now 2 remain. Then I run the program yet again, and finally all links are replaced.

Here is the snippet:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbPart = doc.WorkbookPart;

            // Replace hyperlink targets
            foreach (var worksheet in wbPart.WorksheetParts)
            {
                var hyperLinkRelations = worksheet.HyperlinkRelationships;
                for (int i = 0; i < hyperLinkRelations.Count(); i++)    
                {
                    var link = hyperLinkRelations.ElementAt(i);
                    try
                    {
                        if (link != null && link.Uri != null && Utils.IsToBeReplaced(link.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
                        {
                            string relationId = link.Id;
                            string destUrl = GetReplacementUrl(link.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                            if (destUrl != null)
                            {
                                worksheet.DeleteReferenceRelationship(link);
                                worksheet.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri(destUrl, UriKind.Absolute), true, relationId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Log(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I have checked the utility methods "IsToBeReplaced()" and "GetReplacementUrl()" are functioning normally. I put a break point and discovered that the URLs that don't get replaced, simply do not show up in the "HyperlinkRelationships" collection.

Here is the excel file that I am working with: https://app.box.com/s/j3ulbxfafzxgcqiaep148a8yq4iy37ow

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your indexing is throwing it off.
As a first attempt I would try working backwards. 
ie something like:

```
var hcount = hyperLinkRelations.Count();
for (int i = hcount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Otherwise, after you delete then add the relationship your i variable updates but the collection has been renumbered / shifted up by one so i will have skipped an element.